# MAS platform written in python

Tags: python, multi-agent

Im looking for a relevant MAS (multi agent system) platform written in python which has the same features and functionality of JADE. 
Any recommendations?. thx.

Answer (score 1):

To my knowledge there is no equivalent to JADE, but there exist several python-based platforms that cover part of JADE functionnalities. Depending of what you are looking for, you might find something interesting.

- [MESA](https://mesa.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/intro_tutorial.html) : no communication, so netlogo-like
- [SPADE](https://spade-mas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/readme.html) : Xmpp based, no mobility
- [Osbrain](https://osbrain.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) : No mobility, but communication and computation asynchronism
- [PADE](https://pade-docs-en.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) : Communication based on Twisted, no mobility, synchronous

Comment: Thank you for your response. I m working in deep learning field so I used python because it is eaiser to implement neural network  with python than java however I want to include  multi agent system in my work therefore it is important for me to found a MAS plateform written in python that ensure communication, mobility and cloning. i.e the features of a MAS.